# How to make random looping time in logitech gaming lua script?

Tags: lua, logitech

i want to set random looping time in logitech lua script but the soft keep telling me
"[string "LuaVM"]:4: attempt to call global 'random' (a nil value)",is some thing wrong?how do i fix this？

```
entfunction OnEvent(event, arg)
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
    local i=1
    for i = 1,random(5,7),1 do
        PressAndReleaseKey("1")
        Sleep(math.random['800,1000'])
    end
end
```

ender code here

Comment: Replace `random` with `math.random`.  Replace square brackets after `math.random` with round parentheses.

Comment: now it say :[string "LuaVM"]:4: attempt to index field 'random' (a function value)   :(

Comment: The syntax of the second random call is most likely not what you want. You try to use `800,1000` as an index, rather than two arguments.

Comment: Replace `math.random['800,1000']` with `math.random(800,1000)`

Comment: problem fix thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)  
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3) then
    for i = 1,math.random(5,8),1 do
        PressAndReleaseKey("1")
        Sleep(800)
    end
end
```

so this is the final answer,its nothing by language wrong.